# How do I add "friends" function in PHP?

Tags: php

Hello stack overflow I need help with this problem.
Ok, I have a flat file database in php it records users , hobbies, fav movies and all.
Now i want to add a buddy system so they can have friends and send messages to each other in php without SQL.

Comment: You should probably be using a SQL database.

Comment: If not sql, you need some sort of database anyway.

Comment: I have Flat File Database as said in the description

Comment: We realize that.  However, you should still be using a SQL database.

Comment: Simply add the 'boddy' as how you made the record of fav movies and hobbies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider having another table (er, flat file?) that maintains links.  "Mark" and "John" are buddies if there exists a row in this table (ff?) that links "Mark" and "John".  I'd recommend using some sort of index (you know, like a primary key).

Suppose you have a users table (or flat file, whatever, it doesn't matter *that* much) that contains users and some data, it looks like this:

```
UID | Username | Hobbies
------------------------
1   | Mark     | Swimming, Sailing, Skiing
2   | John     | Biking, Paragliding
3   | Suzie    | Flying, Skiing
```

And you have this other friends table (again, flat file, whatever...):

```
Pair ID | A  | B
----------------
1       | 1  | 2
2       | 2  | 3
```

We've encoded in this friends table that Mark and John are friends, and that John and Suzie are friends, but with the absence of relation 1 and 3, we know that Mark and Suzie are not friends (at least according to our records).

Note that if you want to get all of John's friends, you have to find all rows in your table (or file) that have John's UID (here = 2) in either column A or column B.

Comment: I like the sarcasm, although it is maybe a little... anti-nice.

Comment: Removed the first line, was a little too sarcastic on second read...fwiw it was aimed at the folks that are shoving SQL at the OP, the question is more abstract than that IMHO.

Comment: Yeah it reads alot better now - and is a great answer to the question as well :)

Answer (score 3):

Well I am afraid there's no magical answer or a magical PHP function you can call to enable this behavior.

If we are to help you at all we really need some more to work with.

If you really, for mysterious reasons, decide to stick without a SQL database - then I would probably still "tilt" towards a SQL like way of storing it. Assuming you're currently storing each user as a row in a file, with each "field" separated by some character - simply add another "field" in the file and have this containing each "id" of every user that they're friends with  (id, being whatever you use for that, could be a name as long as it is unique).

As for the messages, another flat file describing the message itself, sender and recipient would probably be the way to go.

Now the real question is, why so eager to avoid using a SQL database? If it is because of having to install a database, try [SQLite](https://www.php.net/sqlite)